# Seconds CountDown Timer

Tags: c#, string, timer

I have a lblCountdown with an int value of 60. I want to make the int value of the lblCountDown decrease with seconds until it reaches 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
   private int counter = 60;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 60;
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Start();
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)

            timer1.Stop();
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 25):

Use Timer for this

```
   private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1; 
   private int counter = 60;
   private void btnStart_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Start();
        lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)
            timer1.Stop();
        lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: this timer will be not accurate enough. Especially in case of interval will be low. But even with 1 sec interval will be bad.

Comment: Why will it not be accurate?

Answer (score 20):

(updated 6.6.2020, because of problems with time calculation)

[image]

Usage:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();


//set to 30 mins
timer.SetTime(30,0);     

timer.Start();

//update label text
timer.TimeChanged += () => Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftMsStr; 

// show messageBox on timer = 00:00.000
timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

//timer step. By default is 1 second
timer.StepMs = 77; // for nice milliseconds time switch
```

and don't forget to `Dispose();` when timer is useless for you;

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CountDownTimer : IDisposable
{
    public Stopwatch _stpWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public Action TimeChanged;
    public Action CountDownFinished;

    public bool IsRunnign => timer.Enabled;

    public int StepMs
    {
        get => timer.Interval;
        set => timer.Interval = value;
    }

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private TimeSpan _max = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);

    public TimeSpan TimeLeft => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) > 0 ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    
    private bool _mustStop => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) < 0;

    public string TimeLeftStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"\mm\:ss");

    public string TimeLeftMsStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();

        if (_mustStop)
        {
            CountDownFinished?.Invoke();
            _stpWatch.Stop();
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public CountDownTimer(int min, int sec)
    {
        SetTime(min, sec);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        SetTime(ts);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        StepMs = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    }

    public void SetTime(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        _max = ts;
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetTime(int min, int sec = 0) => SetTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(min * 60 + sec));

    public void Start() {
        timer.Start();
        _stpWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        _stpWatch.Stop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Reset();
        Pause();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int segundo = 0;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    segundo++;
    label1.Text = dt.AddSeconds(segundo).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, it may help someone. You'll need a label & a timer.
I wrote it on the form load because I'm working with a personal project, but you may add it's functionality by putting it inside a button.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (int.Parse(label_time_left.Text) != 0){
            int futureText = int.Parse(label_time_left.Text) - 1;
            label_time_left.Text = futureText.ToString();
        } else {
            // actions when the timer ends 
        }
}
```

As you see the way it works it's pretty simple :) Just parsing

Answer (score -1):

**Hey please add code in your project,it is easy and i think will solve your problem.**

```
    int count = 10;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count--;
        if (count != 0 && count > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = count / 60 + ":" + ((count % 60) >= 10 ? (count % 60).ToString() : "0" + (count % 60));
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "game over";

        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1;

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

    }
```

Answer (score -5):

You need a public class for Form1 to initialize.

See this code:

```
namespace TimerApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter = 60;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Insert your code from before
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Again insert your code
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this and it all worked fine

If you need anymore help feel free to comment :)