# C# countdown timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown using C# and show the time in format:

```
hour:minutes:seconds
```

I've tried this:

```
 var minutes = 3; //countdown time
  var start = DateTime.Now;
  var end = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes);
  Thread.Sleep(1800);
  if (??) // I tried DateTime.Now > end not works
  {
       //... show time
      label1.Text = "..."; 
  } 
  else 
  {
     //done 
      label1.Text = "Done!"; 
  }
```

Different ways to solve this problem also appeared. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to periodically update the label, you'll need something like a loop.

Comment: @javasocute I he did, I'd have my doubts about his sanity. This is Winforms, and .net has perfectly fine mechanisms for dealing with such stuff. No need to bring in javascript for such a little thing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should not use `Thread.Sleep` here. `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread blocks the UI, and using it on another thread leads to additional complexity due to thread synchronization.

If you have C# 5 or the async CTP you probably can write code very similar to what you did, since you then get a continuation based equivalent of `Thread.Sleep` that doesn't block the UI.

In standard C# 4 I'd use a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

To start the countdown:

```
var minutes = 3; //countdown time
var start = DateTime.UtcNow; // Use UtcNow instead of Now
endTime = start.AddMinutes(minutes); //endTime is a member, not a local variable
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

In the timer handler you write:

```
TimeSpan remainingTime=endTime-DateTime.UtcNow;
if(remainingTime<TimeSpan.Zero)
{
   label1.Text = "Done!";
   timer1.Enabled=false; 
}
else
{
  label1.Text = remainingTime.ToString();
}
```

For other formatting options see [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx).

One issue that remains with this code is that it will not work correctly if the system clock changes.

When using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow` it will also break when switching from/to daylight saving or changing the timezone. Since you want to identify a certain point in time (and not a display time) you should use UTC instead of local time.

Comment: Thanks very much! +1 for good answer, but I have one problem in statament: `Error:Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int'` how I fix it?

Comment: @TheMask Use `TimeSpan.Zero` instead of `0`

Comment: CodeInChaos:The guy that things really work. Works perfect. Thanks very much. :)

Comment: +1 for the working code. A quick question though, you mentioned not to use Now, instead use UtcNow. I have checked it with both the options, and it works well both ways. Any specific reason why you would prefer UtcNow over Now?

Comment: @Rahul My last paragraph already addresses that. If your code is running when daylight saving switches on/off `DateTime.Now` will jump by an hour. And then there is the more philosophical reason that I think the design of `DateTime` isn't very good when working with local times, so I avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks @CodeInChaos. Totally missed that part the first time around! It makes sense.

Comment: The if does not work for me. I used this: if (remainingTime.TotalSeconds <= 0) { do stuff}

Comment: @Rob Strange. Comparing timespans directly works for me. Can you explain what exactly didn't work?

Comment: I run Visual Studio 2010 Free edition with C# here, it did not understand TimeSpan.Zero.  So that did not work whereas the code I mentioned does work for me.

Comment: Use this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191576/seconds-countdown-timer

Answer (score 7):

I would use a timer something like this. First a couple of instance variables.

```
private int _countDown = 30; // Seconds
private Timer _timer;
```

and in the constructor or load event

```
_timer = new Timer();
_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
_timer.Interval = 1000;
_timer.Start();
```

and then finally the event handler

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _countDown--;
    if (_countDown < 1)
    {
        _countDown = 30;
    }
    lblCountDown.Text = _countDown.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a *Timer*, as this would handle all the problems like UI-locking.
You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`-Timer. In the MSDN library you can find samples of the use of it.

The WinForms-Timer handles also the invoking across the Timer-thread and the UI-thread.

- SeriTools

Answer (score -1):

Your code sets up the variables then goes to sleep for 3 minutes so the if-statement isn't executed until it leaves the sleep state. Either set up a new thread to update the UI or do something like this...

```
while (DateTime.now < end) {
  label1.Text = "...";
  Thread.Sleep(#); //Pick a second, or 5 or whatever
}

label1.Text = "Done!";
```

With a 2nd thread you can still do stuff in your program while it works. "Done!" will appear once it finishes.

Comment: Use a timer, not `Thread.Sleep()`. Using sleep is a waste of a thread.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'm not a C# guy at heart and was just building off of his code.

Comment: Budgeting your threads is a good practice but not a requirement. The major caveat is locking up the UI if UI is being used.