# How to do a 30 minute count down timer

Tags: c#, timer

I want my `textbox1.Text` to countdown for 30 minutes. So far I have this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timeX = new Timer();
        timeX.Interval = 1800000;
        timeX.Tick += new EventHandler(timeX_Tick);
    }

    void timeX_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what do i put here?
    }
}
```

However I'm now stumped. I checked Google for answers but couldn't find one matching my question.

Comment: are you just trying to set the textbox to the value of the time remaining?

Comment: There are plenty of examples about countdown. I am not sure that you really checked Google for it. [Google search](https://www.google.com.tr/#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=c#+countdown+example&oq=c#+countdown+example&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i8i30.269.3872.0.4277.20.17.0.3.3.1.197.2302.0j17.17.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.mqNHJX3RD9o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.ZWU&fp=b8296490b2a806eb&biw=1173&bih=858) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191576/seconds-countdown-timer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c943b880-a3bd-4ad0-8f12-c57615522501

Comment: The question can be distilled to "How to compute the difference in times?" In .NET this is as simple as `dateTime2 - dateTime1` (e.g. `nowTime - startTime`) which returns a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) that represents the difference. See the TotalSeconds/TotalMinutes properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is set the value of your Texbox to count down from 30 Minutes. You will first need to change your timer interval to something smaller than 30Minutes. Something like `timeX.Interval = 1000;` which will fire every second. then set up your event like so:

```
 int OrigTime = 1800;
 void timeX_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     OrigTime--;
     textBox1.Text = OrigTime/60 + ":" + ((OrigTime % 60) >= 10 ?  (OrigTime % 60).ToString() : "0" + OrigTime % 60);
 }
```

Also in your button click, you must add the following line: `timeX.Enabled = true;` In order to start the timer.

Comment: @JustWork Ah i see what you were saying added to the answer.

Comment: This method is prone to drifting and will be inaccurate if the computer enters sleep/suspend modes. It also relies on a known interval time.

Comment: @user2246674 only if you are doing something fairly scientifically accurate would it drift enough to even be noticable. Those two operations in the event take sub nanosecond timings on any modern pc, so unless you need to worry about sub nanosecond differences you should be good to go. Obviously as the complexity of the event grows so would the drift but for something this simple there is no reason to even worry about it.

Comment: -1: too much math that's hard to maintain, extra-long ternary operator that's hard to read, reinventing the wheel

Comment: @StenPetrov Umm what? math thats hard to maintain? are you kidding me its a divide and a modulus? Plus a stupidly simple inline if? are you really saying that you could not maintain this code?

Comment: @Nomad101 the things that get hard to maintain always start as innocent little line here and there. For example changing the duration won't be obvious after the code has been long forgotten. Also small delays/accelerations in event firing can build up error in your timer for long intervals, the output format is not immediately clear from your code - so, yes, it's a horrible piece of code

Comment: @StenPetrov first of all unless the amount of seconds in a minute ever changes that code will work for any amount of time that you want from 1 second and above. Those small delays and accelerations would only add what a few milliseconds at max, and again those are negligible unless you are doing scientifically accurate results which the OP is not. Moving on if you are saying you cannot read that code, its really simple you have total seconds remaining divided by 60 now can you not tell me what that equals?

Comment: @Nomad101 if you can't see the problem that's fine by me. For this small example it won't matter much but giving this solution to a nood developer leads him to believe it's OK to write such mess in any size of project

Comment: @Nomad101: I'm with Sten on this one. I very well can read the code, but it's not immediately obvious what it's trying to do. You'd do well to split your long assignment into 2 or 3 variables. As it is, I need to parse the code to understand, while if it were split up, it would be immediately obvious that this part calculates the minutes, that part the seconds and finally, all that gets formatted nicely

Comment: This really is a bad piece of code.  Consider using a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I have to agree with the naysayers.  Ran it on my system and after 1/2 hour it was off by 24 seconds.  Think how far off it will be after several hours...

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple example similar to the code you posted:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowCountDown
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;

            var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };

            timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>    
                textBox1.Text =
                    (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
                    .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");

            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will result in "stutter seconds" because the timer may be called twice during the same second. The period must be at least < 500ms (half the period of what is being observed) when the absolute delta time is shown with such coarse precision.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest thing you can do, is use a 1 minute timer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace countdowntimer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer timeX;
        private int minutesLeft;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timeX = new Timer(){Interval = 60000};
            timeX.Tick += new EventHandler(timeX_Tick);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            minutesLeft=30;
            timeX.Start();
        }

        void timeX_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(minutesLeft--<=0)
            {
              timeX.Stop();
              // Done!
            }
            else
            {
              // Not done yet...
            }
            textBox1.Text = minutesLeft + " mins remaining";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only get one event fired, once the 30 minutes has passed. In order to keep updating your UI continuously you'll have to make the events more frequent and add a condition inside the event handler to tell the count-down to stop once 30 minutes has passed.

You can do the time calculations easily by using TimeSpan and DateTime.

You'll also want to make sure your UI code runs on the UI thread, hence the `Invoke`.

```
  timeX.Interval = 500;

...


  TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
  DataTime startedAt = DateTime.Now;
  void timeX_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
       if ((DateTime.Now - startedAt)<timeSpan){
          Invoke(()=>{
             TimeSpan remaining = timeSpan - (DateTime.Now - startedAt);
             textBox.Text = remaining.ToString(); 
          });
       } else
          timeX.Stop();
  }
```

Comment: @user2246674 you're probably correct about Forms.Timer, just remove the Invoke if needed. Changed the interval to 500ms to prevent the stutter.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this will work for u

> set timer interval=1000

```
minremain=1800000; //Should be in milisecond
timerplurg.satrt();

 private void timerplurg_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       minremain = minremain - 1000;
        string Sec = string.Empty;
        string Min = string.Empty;
        if (minremain <= 0)
        {
            lblpurgingTimer.Text = "";
            timerplurg.Stop();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(minremain));

            var seconds = timeSpan.Seconds;
            var minutes = timeSpan.Minutes;
            if (seconds.ToString().Length.Equals(1))
            {
                Sec = "0" + seconds.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Sec = seconds.ToString();
            }
            if (minutes.ToString().Length.Equals(1))
            {
                Min = "0" + minutes.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Min = minutes.ToString();
            }
            string Totaltime = "Purge Remaing Time: " + Min + ":" + Sec;
            lblpurgingTimer.Text = Totaltime;
            }
         }
```