# TimeSpan countdown between given dates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I would to calculate between two given dates the `TimeSpan`, counting down to 0 days. I have the following code:

```
partial void mExpiration_Compute(ref string result)
    {

        DateTime a = mExpiryDate.AddMonths(-1);
        DateTime b = mExpiryDate;

        TimeSpan ts = b.Subtract(a);

        // Difference in days.
        int c = ts.Days;

        result = Convert.ToString(c);

    }
```

If the `TimeSpan` is currently 31, then I would like the reducing balance time. Example: "You have 24 days to expiry date." Note: The balance reducing is ( 31, 30, .., 24 etc)

How do I count down between given dates.

Comment: It gives me correct 31 days in visual studio 2015.... what is the value of mExpiryDate for me i had set for DateTime.Now

Comment: The value of  mExpiryDate is 02/09/215 minus mExpiryDate.AddMonths(-1) of 02/08/2015

Comment: I'm certainly sure the above code works and returns 31 days for me. i suggest post rest of code. because this is working as expected for me

Comment: I agree with you, the code works. The problem is I would a countdown to 0 days, 31 days minus each day down to 0 days

Comment: I really didn't understand what you need as output!! can you post what output you are expecting??

Comment: This is done for 30 mins countdown. But you might get the hint from it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620234/how-to-do-a-30-minute-count-down-timer)

Comment: TimeSpan is currently 31, then I would like the reducing balance time. Example: "You have 24 days to expiry date." Note: The balance reducing is ( 31, 30..etc)

Comment: Just keep a timer of 24 hrs and keep subtracting 24 hrs from the timespan...

Comment: The result never changes, because you **always** subtract one month.  You want to be using `DateTime.Now` or some variant.

Comment: Yes but the mExpiryDate is a fixed date.

Answer (score 0):

Your function never returns anything other 31, because you are calculating the days remaining exactly one month relative to the expiry date (i.e. the function **always** calculates the days between `02/09/215` and `02/08/2015`, thus always returns a constant value).

Assuming your `mExpiryDate` is persisted and does not change, this is how I would calculate the days remaining (relative to the current date):

```
TimeSpan ts = mExpiryDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
return ts.Days;
```

Comment: The mExpiryDate.AddMonths(-1) must be specified as the notice is triggered ("You have 24 days to expiry date). DateTime.Now is not a correct time between expiration period.

Comment: So, it sounds like you need additional logic to only set your "notification" if the days are less than zero.  To reiterate, if the expiryDate DOES NOT CHANGE, then your function will ALWAYS return 31.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a parameter. Is this what you need:

```
static DateTime mExpiryDate = DateTime.Parse("09/29/2015");
public static void Main()
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    var noticeDate = DateTime.Parse("09/05/2015");
    mExpiration_Compute(ref result, noticeDate);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static void mExpiration_Compute(ref string result, DateTime noticeDate)
{
    DateTime a = noticeDate;
    DateTime b = mExpiryDate;
    TimeSpan ts = b.Subtract(a);
    result = string.Format("You have {0} days to expiry date.", ts.Days);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9mDPx2

Comment: Yes, but the output is not a loop condition. It reflects a single date.

Comment: Ok so you have one date mExpiryDate and you need to count down to another date. I don't see the other date in your code. Right now both date a and date b are based on mExpiryDate and therefore your difference will always be 31. Do you want to count down from mExpiryDate to the current date?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the logic of your form, I guess the question is wether expiry date exists or not.

If it exists, retrieve it; if not, create it as of today and add one month.

Then calculate the days to expiration.

It would go like this (stand-alone code, adjust to your application):

```
// Choose either setting 1. or 2. for mExpiryDate.
// Here setting 1. is active:

//      1. Simulate expiry date already set on August 17th.
DateTime mExpiryDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 17);

//      2. Expiry date not set.
//DateTime mExpiryDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);

TimeSpan ts = mExpiryDate.Subtract(DateTime.Today);

// Difference in days.
int c = ts.Days;

string result = Convert.ToString(c);
```

This will on this day, 2015-09-01, return 16.

Answer (score 0):

This the solution for the countdown between given dates.

```
    partial void mExpiration_Compute(ref string result)
    {

        DateTime expStart = mExpiryDate.AddMonths(-1);
        DateTime expDate = mExpiryDate;
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        // Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
        TimeSpan expSpanGivenDates = expDate.Subtract(expStart);
        TimeSpan expSpanDateNow = expDate.Subtract(currentDate);

        // Difference in days
        int numGivenDays = expSpanGivenDates.Days;
        int numNowDays = expSpanDateNow.Days;
        int calculateDays = numGivenDays - (numGivenDays - numNowDays);

        int days = 0;

        if (calculateDays >= 0 && calculateDays < 31)
        {
            days = calculateDays;
        }

        result = Convert.ToString(days);

    }
```

It will return the number of days left between two given dates. It will be 0 before and after expiry period.

> The output would be: 0 0 31 24 8 9 0 0 0 .....

Answer (score -1):

This works good!

```
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTimeFormatted
    {
        get
        {
            if (FinishedOn != null &&
                StartedAt != null)
            {
                TimeSpan durationCount = new TimeSpan();

                int hours = 0;
                int minutes = 0;
                int seconds = 0;

                var times = Segments.Select(c => c.ElapsedTimeFormatted).ToList();

                foreach (var time in times)
                {
                    TimeSpan timeParse = TimeSpan.Parse(time);

                    hours = hours + (int)timeParse.Hours;
                    minutes = minutes + (int)timeParse.Minutes;
                    seconds = seconds + (int)timeParse.Seconds;

                    durationCount = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
                }

                return durationCount;
            }

            return new TimeSpan();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just add code to your answer. Explain what it's doing so others could learn from your answer.

Comment: Btw. your example isn't working as all variables are missing.