# C# Countdown Timer Then Do Something

Tags: c#, timer

Looked everywhere, but everywhere i look theres a different way to do a countdown timer. Finally found some simple code. How do I make it do something when the time is complete.

This part is next to InitializeComponent();

```
timerlabel1.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720).ToString();

private void countdownTimer()
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;

    var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };

    timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
        timerlabel1.Text =
            (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
            .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");

    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is where i need help, how do i make it do something when the time is done. I tried if timer.Enabled =false; Do This. Cant figure it out.

Comment: Create a field to count how many ticks. If the full time has passed disable the timer and do something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seconds CountDown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191576/seconds-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution :**   you can assign the total seconds `[TotalMinutes*60]` into some variable and `decrement` each time the `Timer Tick` event raises.

if the `totalseconds` value becomes `zero` then `stop` the timer by calling `timer.Stop()` method.

Try This:

```
       public int tootalsecs = 720 * 60;
       private void countdownTimer()
       {
         var startTime = DateTime.Now;

         var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };

         timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
         {
            if (tootalsecs==0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                timerlabel1.Text =
               (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
                   .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
                tootalsecs--;
            }
        };
             timer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ended up using this instead

Answer (score 0):

try this may work for you

```
var timer=new Timer();
timer.Interval=1000;
timer.tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
int i=0;

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(i<TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720))
{
 timerlabel1.Text =
            (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
            .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
}
else
{
timer.Stop();
/* do other work Here */
}
i++;
}
```

Try with this may work for you.

Comment: try to use as `System.IO.Timer timer;` and in Main function `timer = new System.IO.Timer();` and rest initialization

Answer (score 0):

As there are couple `Timer` classes available ([`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) I will advice you to go with `System.Timers.Timer`.

It provides `Elapsed` event, instead of `Tick` event. That's what you're looking for.

```
// Create a timer with a ten second interval.
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do as below.

Initialize in global scope.

```
var target;
timerlabel1.Text =target= DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720));
```

Add a Timer and in `timer1_Tick` write the below code

```
var span = targetTime - DateTime.Now;

 if (span.TotalSeconds > 0)
  {
//it will continue till the time ends. 
    var temp = span.ToString();
    temp=temp.Substring(0, 8);
    timerlabel1.Text = temp;
  }
 else
//do your work here
```

Don't forget to validate the answer or mark as answer if it close to your need