# calculation compile issue with c# timer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, timer, system.net

I have a windows form with a label, and a **system.net timer** called `aTimer`.

The timer is created in an external class like this:

```
// Create a timer with a 3 minute interval.
common.aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
common.aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 3 minutes (180000 milliseconds).
common.aTimer.Interval = 180000; // 3000; //  
common.aTimer.Enabled = true;
mTimerRunning = true;
```

and in my form I run the code `OnTimedEvent` to kick off a background worker

I want to show on my label the number of seconds before the next action is taken.

I tried this but it won't compile:

```
lblStatus.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
        lblStatus.Text = "timer running - Check inbox in " & common.aTimer.Interval - common.aTimer.Elapsed & " seconds!";
                    }));
```

I have a compile error `The event 'System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

So what is the correct way to do this?

Ideally every tick of the timer I would update the label to show when the nxt run will happen.

Comment: I found the answer [StackOverFlow: Seconds CountDown Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191576/seconds-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're from VB background.

Following is not a valid c# code.

```
lblStatus.Text = "timer running - Check inbox in " & common.aTimer.Interval - common.aTimer.Elapsed & " seconds!";
```

- `&` is not used for string concatenation in c#, use `+` operator instead. [Or even better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).
- `aTimer.Interval` is double, `aTimer.Elapsed` is an event. You can't add it. It doesn't even makes sense.

Comment: +1 yeah I changed the '+' to a '&' in case that was the issue. Is there a way to get the count of ticks - I guess that's what I want.